# .net CORE how to AddJsonFile() with specific path?

Tags: linux, angular, asp.net-core

I just deployed my .net core project to Ubuntu server , which hosting by Kestrel. On frontEnd i am using Angular 4 with cli , it shows some data to edit , delete etc. through API call. Backend is just simply API to do CRUD operations. Both Backend and Frontend are hosting by Kestrell. Deployment is successful , app is working as expected **except** if i change `AddJsonFile()` property.
I am confusing about AddJsonFile() propert to set constant path for it.

this is the program.cs :

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var jsonFilePath = "/wwwroot/backend/publish/hosting.json";
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile(jsonFilePath, optional: false)
        //.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false)  -- working

        .AddCommandLine(args)

        .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        //.UseUrls("http://*:8088", "http://0.0.0.0:8088")

        .UseEnvironment("Development")
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

        host.Run();

        //BuildWebHost(args).Run();
```

}

this is the Configure method on Startup.Cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");


        //Kestrel - static files hosting
        //Default : under wwwroot folder
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

    }
```

On ubuntu,  all project files are under **wwwroot/backend/publish** folder.
 Frontend folder is inside publish folder. hosting.json is also in root folder of project. Inside hosting.json i set ports :

```
{
  "server.urls": "http://*:8088;http://*:8089"
}
```

On ubuntu server 8088 and 8089 are **internal ports** , they re forwarded to 9388 and 9389 external ports. So i can able to reach website with 172.17.2.43:9389 and 172.17.2.43:9388 from outside network

with this setting :`.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false)` both backend and frontend  running  without any error. But everytime i connect to server with putty i have to go to publish folder by typing cd /path then dotnet myapp.dll etc. To save my time i have created bash script on **root folder** of ubuntu to run project:

```
dotnet backend/publish/myapp.dll
```

When i run the bash script , dotnet gives an error says : hosting.json  file cannot be found , so i changed to

```
.AddJsonFile(jsonFilePath, optional: false)
```

When i run bash script again , it looks like app is running , says :

```
Now listening on: http://[::]:8088
Now listening on: http://[::]:8089
Application started.
```

When i doing api call with postman , it works.
But the  website gives error:

```
GET http://172.17.2.43:9389/ 404 (Not Found)
contentscript.js:88 Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://172.17.2.43:9389/
    at contentscript.js:88
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:88
popup.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelected' of undefined
    at popup.js:7
```

I have no idea what is the problem , app looks running , api calls give response , but cannot reach the website.

**Updated(Solved)**

As i suspected if you run  `dotnet [Path]/Projectname.dll` command outside of project dll folder(on my project it is publish) on linux , it doesnt host static files

Ex:

```
project folder on linux : (root)/wwwroot/backend/publish
wwwroot of project :     (root)/wwwroot/backend/publish/wwwroot
```

when you in root folder if you type `dotnet /wwwroot/backend/publish/MyProject.dll`

Kestrel just hosting backend dll file , it couldn't find static files so when you go to web site it gives 404 error. To fix it you need to add `.UseWebRoot()` with correct path parameter when initialize WebHostBuilder() class on Main() method.

```
 .AddJsonFile("/wwwroot/backend/publish/ + "hosting.json", optional: false)
 .UseWebRoot("/wwwroot/backend/publish/wwwroot");
```

If you dont want to type the path hardcoded you can use like this:

```
var publishPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var webRoot =  publishPath + "/wwwroot"; //wwwroot/backend/publish/wwwroot
```

this is the Main method of my App which is working as expected:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var publishPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        var webRoot =  publishPath + "/wwwroot"; ///wwwroot/backend/publish/wwwroot

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(publishPath)
        .AddJsonFile(publishPath + "/hosting.json", optional: false)
        //.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false)  -- working
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();


        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        //.UseUrls("http://*:8088", "http://0.0.0.0:8088")

        .UseEnvironment("Development")
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(publishPath)
        .UseWebRoot(webRoot)

        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

        host.Run();

        //BuildWebHost(args).Run();

    }
```

Comment: You can simplify the `.AddJsonFile(publishPath + "/hosting.json", optional: false)` statement like this: `.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false)`. No need to concatenate the paths because `AddJsonFile` method takes a **relative** path as the parameter.